# PCL1.81 boost1.58 make エラー boost::filesystem::path_traits::dispatch(boost::filesystem::directory_entry const&, std::string&)

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

PCL1.81を[このサイト](https://larrylisky.com/2016/11/03/point-cloud-library-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts/)を参考にセットアップし
cmake後makeしたところ、以下のエラーが出てmakeが通らず困っています

> ../../lib/libpcl_visualization.so.1.8.1.99:
>   `boost::filesystem::path_traits::dispatch(boost::filesystem::directory_entry
>   const&, std::string&)' に対する定義されていない参照です collect2: error: ld returned 1
>   exit status
>   visualization/tools/CMakeFiles/pcl_hdl_viewer_simple.dir/build.make:139:
>   ターゲット 'bin/pcl_hdl_viewer_simple' のレシピで失敗しました make[2]: ***
>
>   [bin/pcl_hdl_viewer_simple] エラー 1 CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1172: ターゲット
>
>   'visualization/tools/CMakeFiles/pcl_hdl_viewer_simple.dir/all'
>
>   のレシピで失敗しました make[1]: ***
>   [visualization/tools/CMakeFiles/pcl_hdl_viewer_simple.dir/all] エラー 2
>   Makefile:160: ターゲット 'all' のレシピで失敗しました make: *** [all] エラー 2

cmakeオプションのWITH_VTKのチェックを外すとまた別の箇所で同じエラーが出ます

> [ 85%] Linking CXX executable ../bin/pcl_train_linemod_template
>   ../lib/libpcl_recognition.so.1.8.1.99:
>   `boost::filesystem::path_traits::dispatch(boost::filesystem::directory_entry
>   const&, std::string&)' に対する定義されていない参照です collect2: error: ld returned 1
>   exit status
>   tools/CMakeFiles/pcl_train_linemod_template.dir/build.make:129: ターゲット
>   'bin/pcl_train_linemod_template' のレシピで失敗しました make[2]: ***
>
>   [bin/pcl_train_linemod_template] エラー 1 CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3340:
>
>   ターゲット 'tools/CMakeFiles/pcl_train_linemod_template.dir/all'
>
>   のレシピで失敗しました make[1]: ***
>   [tools/CMakeFiles/pcl_train_linemod_template.dir/all] エラー 2
>   Makefile:160: ターゲット 'all' のレシピで失敗しました make: *** [all] エラー 2

OS: ubuntu 16.04

PCL 1.81
boost 1.58

ご助言どうかよろしくお願いします。